# Format XML while reading it with linq

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, string-formatting

My xml file looks like this:

```
<addresses>
    <addr kind="list">https://someaddr.com/?param={0}&param2={1}</addr>
</addresses>
```

When I read this node I'd like linq no to try to format it, because when I do:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("that_file.xml");
```

I get `NotSupportedException`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *no try to format it*, but I would say your XML is invalid. `&` has special meaning in XML content, and it has to be replaced with `&amp;`:

```
<addresses>
    <addr kind="list">https://someaddr.com/?param={0}&amp;param2={1}</addr>
</addresses>
```

That can be loaded using `XElement.Load` method just fine.